# How to get the task is finished / Completed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have list of tasks run based on the queue but i need to check if the task is completed or not. Based on the status returned from each task i have to execute the function.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
() =>
{
    string fileName;
    while (!filePaths.IsCompleted)
    {
        if (!filePaths.TryTake(out fileName)) continue;
        this.ReadFileContents(fileName, VMCallBack);
    }
}, _cts.Token);
```

Comment: Do you need to wait until the task finishes execution?

Answer (score 1):

`StartNew` returns a object of `Task`. You can collect those and check the `IsCompleted` property to find out if it is completed or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(...);
myTask.Wait();
//now do stuff after completion
```